# How do I comply with the "bundle the license text" requirement of Apache 2.0 for embedded software?

Tags: apache-2.0, license-notice, font

I'm writing software for a "closed" embedded device. I want to use fonts licensed under the Apache 2.0 license in it. I know it's legal to do that, but I'm stumbling over this text from the license:

> You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a copy of this License;

I'm thinking about hosting the license on our company's website and print a link to our copy of the license in the paper user's guide we distribute with the hardware.

Would that be enough?

Comment: Since you are using fonts, I assume that you have some UI of sorts. Are you extremely spaced-constrained on this device to the point that including the text of the Apache license would be problematic?

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne: For all we know, the device might easily be a printer of sorts (regular printer, or for labels/price tags) without any display. Hopefully, the author returns to answer.

Comment: Do you mean that you'll be using text displayed in those fonts (such as on a web page) or you'll be including the font files for generation of new text on/from your device?

Answer (score 2):

Conventionally, most copyright holders would consider that adequate if you include a copy of the license in the users' guide (and not just a link).  The intent of that clause is to make sure that downstream users are aware of their rights to the licensed material.

To fulfill the letter of the requirement, you should also bundle the license in the program files, even though the user has no way to access the file.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for "most copyright holders would consider that adequate"?  I'd be a little surprised if it were so, since it's an explicit violation of the actual licence terms.  The OP is giving out a users' guide with every device shipped, so it's not like (s)he's short of an opportunity to fulfil the terms to the letter.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that he said a *link* in the user's guide, not a full copy of the license.  Amending my answer per your comment, thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see.  Glad to help, and I have much less in the way of bones to pick with your answer now.  One remains, though: why do you feel that a full paper copy of the licence fails to satisfy Apache2 s4a?  I see no requirement that the licence copy be part of the program files.

Comment: It does if they can make sure that the paper copy stays with the hardware.  However, HW is often redistributed, and redistributors are not good about paper.  Having a digital copy of the license in the firmware files -- however buried -- is a good CYA against any accusations of not including the license.

Comment: For the OP: the reason why a *link* to the license in your user's guide isn't adequate is that your website could vanish or move.

Comment: That's a pretty good point.  I don't think it's necessary, but it could well be very prudent - +1 from me.